# No "eslint" targets found

Tags: npm, gruntjs, bigcommerce

I have a Gruntfile.js like this.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);
    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
        jitGrunt: {
            staticMappings: {
                scsslint: 'grunt-scss-lint'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-run');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['eslint', 'jest', 'scsslint', 'svgstore'])
};
```

And when I run the `grunt` it says.

> grunt

> No "eslint" targets found.

eslint is already installed and I even created the configuration file using

`./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init`
And this is the content of  `.eslintrc.js`.

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 13
    },
    "rules": {
    }
};
```

Any opinions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you downloaded the codebase for the theme, it may be missing the "grunt" folder. If your project is missing this folder, try adding the one from Cornerstone: https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/tree/master/grunt

Answer (score 0):

Per the BigCommerce [documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/installing-stencil-cli/troubleshooting-your-setup) around eslint errors -- If bundling your theme triggers multiple lint errors related to the bundle.js file, your theme is missing the .eslintignore file.

You can retrieve this file from the Cornerstone repo. Once you add this in, re-run the bundle command.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Heather Barr
You mean my error is coming from missing .eslintignore file?

Comment: I created .eslintignore file from Cornerstone and run `grunt` but it still shows same error

Comment: Okay I see, I believe Matt's answer may be more of what you're looking for as this happened to them once before! take a look and let us know! :)